# Bash - List and Sort Files and Their Sizes and by Name and Size

Tags: bash, sorting, size

I am trying to figure out how to sort a list of files by name and size.

How do I sort by file name and size using "**du -a**" and not show directories?

Using "**du -a**"

```
1   ./locatedFiles
0   ./testDir/j.smith.c
0   ./testDir/j.smith
1   ./testDir/sampleFunc/arrays
2   ./testDir/sampleFunc
0   ./testDir/j.smith.txt
0   ./testDir/testing
0   ./testDir/test2
0   ./testDir/test3
0   ./testDir/test1
0   ./testDir/first/j.smith
0   ./testDir/first/test
1   ./testDir/first
1   ./testDir/second
1   ./testDir/third
6   ./testDir
```

How can I list all files without directories, add files sizes, and sort by files name first, then by size?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you want it sorted on filename? or path?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use this:

```
find -type f -printf "%f  %s %p\n"|sort
```

Explanation:

- -type f to find files only
- -printf to print the output in specific format:

  - %f to print the file name
  - %s to print the file size
  - %p to print the whole file name (i.e. with leading folders) - you can omit this if you want

Then run through sort which sorts in the order given above (i.e. file name, then file size, then file path). The output would be something like this (part of the output shown):

```
...
XKBstr.h 18278 ./extensions/XKBstr.h
XlibConf.h 1567 ./XlibConf.h
Xlib.h 99600 ./Xlib.h
Xlibint.h 38897 ./Xlibint.h
Xlocale.h 1643 ./Xlocale.h
xlogo11 219 ./bitmaps/xlogo11
....
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `sort` command

```
$ find -type f -printf $'%s\t%f\n' | sort -k2,2 -k1,1n
```

sort by second field(name), then first field(size) numerically.

Comment: Note that these `sort` options (mutatis mutandis) are required for the `-printf` method as well.  You might also want to then remove fields, e.g., using `cut` or some such.

Comment: you can `--max-depth=1` to `du` to restrict only to the current folder, but it will still list folders but not its contents.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers so far say, this is not really a bash problem.

`du` pretty much insists on telling you about directories: if you point it at a directory, then with or without `-a` it will tell you about it.

If you have the GNU `du`, though, you can tell it to read a list of NUL-terminated file names from stdin, so you can use `find` to produce the list:  `find ... -print0 | du --files0-from=-` (you don't need the `-a` flag here).  (If you don't have the `--files0-from` option you can still invoke `du` relatively efficiently using `xargs`; see the `xargs` documentation.)

If you have GNU `du`, though, you probably have GNU `find`, which has `-printf` as described by @icyrock.com.  Just use that.  Then use an explicit `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
$ stat --printf='%s %n\n' * | sort -k2,2 -k1n
```

Get the file size(%s) and name(%n) with stat and pipe it to sort which sequentially sorts it by name and size.